# word 2003 how do you redraw a window?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-2003, word-2003

Sorry, I know this should be a basic question but I can't seem to find the answer.

How do you redraw an office word 2003 window in c#? right now I have the window minimizing and maximizing.

Thanks.